# SDL2 | 'SDL_ConvertSurface()' Creates a Segment Fault only on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, cmake, sdl-2

This is a weird problem. My code works on Windows and on Arch Linux. But when Ubuntu is involved, problems arise. I think the problem may be something to do with libraries/dependencies considering the code works on another Linux system and Windows. What happens is my code runs for a little bit, then crashes. The original code looks like this:

```
SDL_Surface* bg = SDL_ConvertSurface(
        IMG_Load("Resources/Engine/launcher.jpg"),
        SDL_GetWindowSurface(GameWindow->SDLWindow)->format,
        0
        );
```

And to debug this code I converted this code to this mess:

```
SDL_Surface* src = IMG_Load("Resources/Engine/launcher.jpg");
    if (!src) { log->error("background didnt load"); SDL_GetError();}
    else log->info("good to go (src)");
    SDL_Surface* fmt = SDL_GetWindowSurface(GameWindow->SDLWindow);
    if (!src) { log->error("window surface didnt load"); SDL_GetError(); }
    else log->info("good to go (fmt)");
    SDL_Surface* bg = SDL_ConvertSurface(src, fmt->format, 0);
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This line Crashes ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
    if (!bg) { log->error("surface wasnt made"); SDL_GetError(); }
    else log->info("good to go (all)");
```

This is labeled as such to match the [SDL2 API for SDL_ConvertSurface()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface)

The output for my debug version of this function is this:

```
...
[2015-08-17 14:37:15.919] [Somnia] [info] good to go (src)
[2015-08-17 14:37:15.919] [Somnia] [info] good to go (fmt)
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

Now since I mentioned that the code might be acting differently because of a lack of a library or something I will show you guys the CMakeList.txt where I link the Libraries. Keep in mind this works on my laptop (Arch Linux) and my Desktop(Windows 10) but not my desktop (Ubuntu).

```
...
pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_search_module(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
pkg_search_module(SDL2NET REQUIRED SDL2_net>=2.0.0)
pkg_search_module(SDL2MIXER REQUIRED SDL2_mixer>=2.0.0)
pkg_search_module(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf>=2.0.0)
...
target_link_libraries(Somnia
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2NET_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2MIXER_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES}
    ${STEAMWORKS_LIBRARY}
)
...
```

Comment: It looks like you're checking `src` twice instead of checking both `src` and `fmt` in the block where you break out your input arguments into explicit variables: `if (!src)...` then later: `if (!src)...`  Second one should probably be `if (!fmt)...`

Comment: You're right. I copied an pasted (opps), it said that the window surface didn't load, so I guess that would be my problem. Let me see if I can fix it knowing that! :)

Comment: Looks unrelated to CMake. You can remove the code and the [cmake] tag.